# PHP require/include coding practices

Tags: php

Just curious...when writing a require/include statement, what do you prefer as better practice?

```
require('filename.php');
```

or

```
require 'filename.php';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always the latter - the same applies to `echo`, `print` and other language constructs, too. **Never add additional parenthesis after language constructs!**

The reason is simple: Using parenthesis makes you believe that `require` is a function - which it is not! For example:

```
if (require('file.php') == false) {
    // do stuff
}
```

You - and probably even most of the senior PHP developers - would say that this compares the return value of the `require`. But it does not! PHP interprets this as:

```
if (require (('file.php') == false)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

which is:

```
if (require '') {
    // do stuff
}
```

If you use parenthesis with language constructs you could as well write:

```
require(((((((((((((((((((('file.php'))))))))))))))))))))
```

Or would you ever write:

```
array(('hi'));
```

That's just as much the same nonsense.

Comment: "Never use parenthesis with language constructs".  So you never use `array` or `exit` with a parameter?  This is really an operator precedence issue, and a fairly contrived one at that.  There is no suggestion in the question.of checking a non-existent return value.  And if you *do* write `require('file.php') == false`, you get an immediate fatal error.  So there's no possibility of subtle bugs.

Comment: @Metthew: With `array` the parenthesis are part of the construct. With `require` they are not. You cannot omit them.

Comment: Thanks nikic! For almost 2 years now, I'm using require('filename.php'), until I bump into a code with a require 'filename.php' construction...and got curious... Thanks for your explanation! :D